# Broken image tag is shown for split second

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, web-frontend

Is there a way to not show the broken image tag for a split second when the page loads?

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/v8DLe/196/

I already use: `onerror="this.style.display ='none'"`

I'd rather still use the img tag and not use a div with `style={{ backgroundImage: ...}}`

Comment: Hide it by default and make it visible after loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make them hidden first. Show them when the `onLoad` event fires.

```css
img {
  display: none;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="abc" alt=" " onload="this.style.display ='block'"/>
<img src="abc" alt=" " onload="this.style.display ='block'"/>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt=" " onload="this.style.display ='block'"/>
<img src="abc" alt=" " onload="this.style.display ='block'"/>
<img src="abc" alt=" " onload="this.style.display ='block'"/>
<img src="abc" alt=" " onload="this.style.display ='block'"/>
```

Comment: If it's display:none will it ever load?

Comment: @AndrewBone Yes it will. It's just a style over the html element. The element is not shown but it is in the DOM. The element will still work as intended. I edited a google logo in to show the code actually works.